# Subscribe / Iterate a List of Mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a list of Rules that return `Mono<Result>`, I need to execute them and return another List of Mono with the result of each function.

`Mono<List< Rule>>`   to    `Mono<List< RuleResult>>`

I have this, which works but blocking the execution seems not correct to me:

```
List<Rule> RuleSet
...
Mono<List<RuleResult>> result= Mono.just(RuleSet.stream().map(rule -> rule.assess(object).block()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

How can I convert this into less blocking version?

I tried the following:

```
//Create a List of Monos
List<Mono<RuleResult>> ruleStream=statefulRuleSet.stream().map(rule -> rule.assess(assessmentObject)).collect(Collectors.toList());

//Cannot convert type
Flux.zip(ruleStream,...)).collectList();

//Not sure how to do this
Flux.fromIterable(ruleStream...).collectList();
```

Perhaps I am thinking of a wrong solution overall, somebody has any pointers?

Comment: "and return another List of Mono with the result of each function" - From the code it looks that you meant "and return a Mono with a List of results of each function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
interface Rule extends Function<Object, Mono<Object>> { }

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Rule rule1 = (o) -> Mono.just(Integer.valueOf(o.hashCode()));
  Rule rule2 = (o) -> Mono.just(o.toString());
  List<Rule> rules = List.of(rule1, rule2);

  Object object = new Object();

  Mono<List<Object>> result = Flux.fromIterable(rules)
    .flatMapSequential(rule -> rule.apply(object)).collectList();

  result.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Using `flatMapSequential` allows you to wait for up to *maxConcurrency* results at the same time. The *maxConcurrency* value can be specified as an additional argument to `flatMapSequential`. In reactor-core 3.3.8 its default value is 256.